# MVC pattern, update multiple views

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have multiple views in my model-view-controller pattern (label and listbox with selected item) 
listbox onSelect event calls controller **setModel(new_model_val)**, which updates views and also highlights listbox so there is cyclic call.

As I understand, I have to pass sender to define which views to update( so I get something like **setModel(new_model_val, sender)**? 
Is it good idea?
What type of sender to use(enum, raw pointer etc)?

Comment: Without more context (specifically about what a sender is/does) it's difficult to say what's a good engineering solution

Comment: sender helps me to identify what view does not require update.

Comment: Yes, but what encapsulates a sender? Is it an object with lots of fields? An ip address? An internally tracked indicator? What is the application's use of the interface? These questions help define what information you need to know in order to easily identify the views that you want to update.